# viewed date in HTML Table to insert to my sql table

Tags: php, html

I am a student  learning programming' I have html table in php page. Called data from sql table to using select* command to HTML table. code here.

```
<?php
**CALLMETHOD**include './dbconfig.php';

if (isset($_GET['soname']))
{
    $soname = $_GET['soname']; // get emp id from the url
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nidahas where  soname='$soname'";

    // execute select query
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // if result has one or more rows
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $type = "";
            $cdo = "";
            $state = "";

            $res = $row['res'];
            $pay = $res * (1 / 100);
            $ba = $res - $pay;

?>

                        <tr style="color: #F60" style="background-color: #FF9">


                        <td><input  value="<?php echo $row['tno']; ?>" name="tno" id="tno" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control   input-md" ></td>


                        <td><input  value="<?php echo $row['uno']; ?>" name="uno" id="uno" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control   input-md" ></td>


                        <td><input  value="<?php echo $row['date']; ?>" name="date" id="date" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control    input-md" ></td>
                        <td><input  value="<?php echo $row['res']; ?>" name="res" id="res" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control   input-md" ></td>
                        <td><input  value="<?php echo $pay; ?>" name="pay" id="pay" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control  input-md" ></td>
                        <td><input  value="<?php echo $ba; ?>" name="ba" id="ba" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control     input-md" ></td>




                         </tr> 
                          <?php
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Use The Button to post input field data in table
**POST METHOD**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="logic/save.php" method="post">
```

table view like this

[image]

I want to all viewd data save (insert) to enother SQL table. My save code like this (save.php file)

```
<?php

include("../dbconfig.php");

if(isset($_POST['btnSave']))
    {       
        for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['tno']); $i++) { // this code used to get all data in table row'
            $tno=$_POST['tno'];
            $soname=$_POST['soname'];
            $uno=$_POST['uno'];
            $date=$_POST['date'];
            $res=$_POST['res'];
            $pay=$_POST['pay'];
            $ba=$_POST['ba'];
          echo count($_POST['tno']);  

                $adddept="INSERT INTO `usavirel` (`tno`,`soname`, `uno`,`date`, `res`,`pay`,`ba`, `rel`) VALUES ('$tno',  '$soname',   '$uno', '$date', '$res', '$pay','$ba','$ba')
             ";
    $result = mysql_query($adddept);
    if($result)
    {
        echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<br>Input data failed");

    }

        }       
    }
```

Above code does not work. How can I insert from all rows data in table. Tables Rows count will Change every select time via IDs. Please guide me sole this Problem.